# Failed cloud tasks are not being retried with task queue retry config

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I'm using google cloud tasks with http triggers to invoke cloud functions.  I've setup the cloud task queue retry parameters as follows:

- max attempts: 2
- Max retry duration: 16
- Min backoff: 1
- Max backoff: 16
- Max doublings: 4

I will often have bursts of tasks which will create around 600 tasks within a second or two.  There are times when about 15% of these will fail (this is expected and intentional).  I'm expecting these failed tasks to retry according to the queue configuration.  Thus I would not expect any task retry schedule to be more than 16 seconds beyond its initially scheduled time.  However, I'm seeing some failed tasks scheduled several minutes out.  Typically, the first few failed tasks will schedule for retry only a few seconds out, but some of the last few failed tasks in this burst will have these retry schedule for many minutes away.

Why are these retry schedules not honoring my retry config?

If it helps, I also have these settings on the queue:

- Max dispatches: 40
- Max concurrent dispatches: 40

Comment: What's the HTTP code that you return when you fail?

Comment: I return status code 500 when I fail.  Perhaps I should return something in 400 range?

Comment: 500 is OK. However, the behavior is strange...

Comment: Just as a follow up, I was never able to solve this directly.  The retries continued to be rescheduled beyond my supplied config.  Instead, I solved by implementing my own retry mechanism where I pass in the current attempt number in a header value.  If attempt number is <= configured max retries, I just create a new message on the queue and increment the attempt number.